# Native crash at signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash

I just have released my Unity app on Google Play Store. However, some of my users are getting `Native crash at signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)` on following devices:

*Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android 4.3), LG K10 LTE (Android 6.0), Highscreen Easy XL (Android 6.0), Sony Xperia C5 Ultra Dual (Android 6.0), Huawei Y635-TL00 (Android 4.4).*

I was unable to reproduce the same crash on my Samsung Galaxy S6 or my friends' devices. I am using Unity 5.6.2f1, API level 16. What may be causing this crash and how should I attempt to fix it?

**Backtrace:**

```
native: pc 00000000004db254  /mnt/asec/com.companyname.app-1/lib/libunity.so
native: pc 00000000004ec69c  /mnt/asec/com.companyname.app-1/lib/libunity.so
native: pc 00000000000d9e24  /mnt/asec/com.companyname.app-1/lib/libunity.so
native: pc 00000000000db2d0  /mnt/asec/com.companyname.app-1/lib/libunity.so
native: pc 000000000031a3b0  /mnt/asec/com.companyname.app-1/lib/libunity.so
native: pc 00000000005eea94  /mnt/asec/com.companyname.app-1/lib/libunity.so
native: pc 000000000001e44c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
native: pc 000000000004e91b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
native: pc 0000000000027860  /system/lib/libdvm.so
native: pc 000000000002be00  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
native: pc 0000000000060a6d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+292)
native: pc 0000000000060a97  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
native: pc 000000000005582b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
native: pc 000000000000cb58  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
native: pc 000000000000ccd4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
```

Comment: Signal 11 crashes are really hard to debug, but the first place i would look is memory usage. Find out if the devices it's crashing on have low memory specs, like less than a gig, if yes then it's probably a memory error with textures or something like that.

Comment: @Ingavaras: have you made any progress on your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that this error occurred when I tried loading many texture-heavy objects with Application.LoadLevelAdditive(). I resolved the problem by simply enabling/disabling the objects when needed (I would initialize them disabled, and would enable them later).